# google sheet to Calender event script not working for my client

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-gsuite

I created a script in Google sheet to automate google calendar events from the sheet. The script works like a charm for my calendar but is not working on my client's calendar even after adding the correct calendar ID. My client is the actual owner of the Google sheet. I just created the script. When my client tries from his end, the script doesn't work and doesn't populate the events into the desired calendar.
I'm not sure what's wrong. Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would gather from the fact that you mentioned your client's involvement that you have some sense of urgency in regard to this matter.  For that reason I suggest that you learn how tto write a better question: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)